# How To Mask a password input in java console

Tags: java, authentication, console, password-protection

I'm building a login system in Java and I'm trying to mask the password input due to security measures but can't seem to find a way around it. This is what I'm Trying to do:

Username:
User1

Password:******

Here's my code to give you an idea

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Username:");
    String Username = Input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Password:");
    String Password = Input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Console](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Try readPassword() method of java
It doesn't mask a * but it hide the input we type to console

```
cnsl = System.console();
char[] pwd = cnsl.readPassword("Password: ");
System.out.println("Password is: "+pwd);
```

like this.......

Answer (score 1):

You can use Console.readPassword() from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html